# reshape in R a pivoted long result

Tags: r, pivot, reshape

** Problem **

Trying to figure how to reshape after a pivot_long task.

1. Use 2 columns (D and T) from jan_vic_elec data set.
2. Create reshaped object naming to a newly reshaped column `key`.
3. Result with be a 'key' column and two variables D and T
4. Define D name T column with values as 'value'
5. You should have a reshaped data with three columns: Date, key, value
6. Make the output new variable name object

```
{r messsage = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
col2Reshape <- pivot_longer(jan_vic_elec, cols = c(starts_with("D"), starts_with("T")))

reshape(col2Reshape, v.names = c('D', "T"), direction = "long")
```

** Error ***

```
Error in reshape(col2Reshape, v.names = c("D", "T"), direction = "long") : no 'reshapeWide' attribute, must specify 'varying'
```

On R documentation, varying specifies "names of sets of variables in the wide format that correspond to single variables in long format (‘time-varying’)"

** Data : jan_vic_electric**

```
Date        D       T 
2014-01-01  175185  26      
2014-01-02  188351  23      
2014-01-03  189086  22      
2014-01-04  173798  20      
2014-01-05  169733  26      
2014-01-06  195241  20      
2014-01-07  199770  20      
2014-01-08  205339  27      
2014-01-09  227334  32      
2014-01-10  258111  34
```

** Data col2Reshape ***

```
Date        name    value 
2014-01-01  Demand  175185      
2014-01-01  Temperature 26      
2014-01-02  Demand  188351      
2014-01-02  Temperature 23      
2014-01-03  Demand  189086      
2014-01-03  Temperature 22      
2014-01-04  Demand  173798      
2014-01-04  Temperature 20      
2014-01-05  Demand  169733      
2014-01-05  Temperature 26
```

Comment: Calling a column or any other object `T` isn't a good idea, because it can get interpreted as shorthand for TRUE—it even shows up that way in the syntax highlighting here. Aside from that, it's unclear what you're asking—it just seems like you're illustrating a task you had

Comment: T was just a placeholder...

Answer (score 1):

How to reshape into key/value columns. Utilize 2 columns (D and T)  and reshape columns to key, value, using pivot_longer, names_to = and values_to = functions. both which specify column names key/value.

```
pivot_longer(jan_vic_elec, cols = c('D', 'T'), names_to = 'key', values_to = 'value')
```